# Capture Image using Python and Open Cv 2.3

Tags: python, image, ubuntu

I am using Linux Mint 12, Kernel 3. I have installed and configured Open CV 2.3.
I can capture images and videos using my camera "through gucview. 
I can capture videos using cheese "but problems happen with photos".
I can read images using Open CV, but I can't capture images from Web cam.
When I capture an image, I get an empty window.
When I check if the image is captured or not, I get True as a result. I am using "Python Bindings"
Any help with that!

Comment: try to post the code giving you problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you have correctly installed ffmpeg and other required stuff for opencv 2.3

If Mint has package for opencv 2.3, completely remove opencv from your computer. and install it again.

http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/install-opencv-2-3-1-and-simplecv-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-arch-linux/

I was facing the same problem in ubuntu 11.10. If Mint doesn't have OpenCV 2.3 package, re-install opencv 2.3.1 from http://www.marcolancini.it/other/opencv_install_231.php

To capture images in opencv 2.3.1

http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/capture-images-and-video-from-camera-in-opencv-2-3-1/